# How to use session inside the href?

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code snippet:

```
 <a href="~/Accounts/AccountsApp.aspx?id='<%# Session("DeptName") & "-" & Session(Eval("id"))% >'" runat="server">View</a>
```

I would like to ask is it something wrong with it? And why it's not working. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using `tostring` function.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 <a href='~/Accounts/AccountsApp.aspx?id=<%# GetValue()  %>'  runat="server">View </a>
```

Code Behind

```
protected string GetValue()
{ 
    string Str="";
    if (Session["DeptName"]!=null && Session["id"]!=null)
    {
        Str = Session["DeptName"].ToString() + "-" + Session["id"].ToString() ;
    }

    return Str;   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<a href="~/Accounts/AccountsApp.aspx?id='<%# Session("DeptName").ToString() & "-" & Session(Eval("id").ToString()).ToString()% >'" runat="server">View</a>
```